# What to use here from or since in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

During a conversation I said

> I've not slept for a long time

She replied

> From when you haven't slept

She should've said since. As from here sounds Kinda unidiomatic

Answer (score 1):

Actually the more idiomatic way to say this would be.

> How long have you had trouble sleeping?

or

> How long has it been since you had a good night's rest?

Neither "from when you haven't slept" nor "Since when you haven't slept" are idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

Or perhaps:

I haven't slept.

Since when have you not slept?

Since when haven't you slept?

Comment: This answer is hard to understand at best. Moreover there already is a perfectly good answer.

Comment: Just offering some different ways to phrase the sentence. Is that not allowed?